# Basis using characters for subspace of class functions

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups, characters

Let $\chi_1,...,\chi_N$ be the irreducible characters of a finite group $G$. Also, suppose $\chi_1,...\chi_m$, with $m < N$, are all the real irreducible characters. And $\chi_{m+1}, \overline{\chi_{m+1}},...,\chi_{n},\overline{\chi_{n}}$ are the remaining irreducible characters (each non-real). So that means $m + 2(n-m) = N$. Is it true that $\{\chi_1,...,\chi_m\} \cup\{\chi_{m+1} + \overline{\chi_{m+1}},...,\chi_{n}+\overline{\chi_{n}}\}$ is a basis for $$\{f:G \to \mathbb{C}:f \text{ is constant on }C_g \cup C_{g^{-1}} \text{ for }g \in G\}$$ where $C_g$ is the conjugacy class of $g$?

If so, can this be proven directly (showing the set is spanning)? I would like to avoid using results relating real conjugacy classes and real irreducible characters.

I would appreciate a hint rather than a full solution. Thank you.

Comment: It may suffice to say any function $f : G \to \mathbb{R}$ is of the form $f(g) = \frac{f(g)+f(g^{-1})}{2}+\frac{f(g)-f(g^{-1})}{2}$ ? And the real part of characters is a basis of even class functions.

Comment: @reuns: what are even class functions? Can you explain your comment a little more?

Comment: $h(g) =\frac{f(g)+f(g^{-1})}{2}$ is even because $h(g) = h(g^{-1})$.

Comment: I see. And where can I find a proof of "real part of characters is a basis of even class functions"? Thanks very much.

Comment: The projection $f \mapsto h=P(f)$ is linear. For $f$ a class function, write $f=\sum_j a_j \chi_j$ and look at $P(\chi_j)$

Comment: Bonus : do you see any orthonormal basis of the even class functions ?

Comment: Following your suggestion using the projection, I managed to show "real part of characters is a basis of even class functions". The original question I asked is in fact exactly that statement anyway.  So that gives me the argument I was looking for.  As for your question, isn't the basis in my post above already orthogonal, so scaling gives an orthonormal basis of even class functions?

Comment: Yes, and $1_{g \in C_{g'} \cup C_{{g'}^{-1}}}$ is another orthogonal basis. Not sure if we can compute the norms needed to normalize easily.

Comment: Quotienting the class functions by $g = g^{-1}$, does it mean we looking at the representations and characters of the quotient group $G / \{\forall g, g = g^{-1} \} =G / G^2$ ?

Comment: If you know the sizes of the conjugacy classes, shouldn't it be fine computing the norm? I was also wondering: what was the purpose of writing $f$ the way you did in your very first comment?

Comment: set of class functions $ = $ even class functions $\oplus$ odd class functions (the basis of the second is $\frac{\chi(g)-\chi(g^{-1})}{2}$), this direct sum is a  consequence of the concept of orthogonal projections in vector spaces.